# Extend Enzyme js

Tags: reactjs, testing, enzyme, jestjs

Is there a way to add a new method to Enzyme js?

for instance, I want to add a `findByTestAttr` method to use this syntax
`wrapper.findByTestAttr('foo')` instead of using `wrapper.find('[data-test="foo"]')`

I know I can fork their repo and extend ReactWrapper and add my method, but I want to know whether is there a solution or not.

Comment: Sure just do ``wrapper.findByTestAttr = function(foo){return wrapper.find('[data-test=' + foo + ']');};`` somewhere at the beginning of one of your scripts and anywhere else in the script you can just call wrapper.findByTestAttr.

Comment: thanks. I need to implement universal helper. in this workaround which you mentioned, I have to define this helper in every test, because `wrapper` is null before shallowing a component.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

so, I found a workaround:

I implemented this function inside my configuration file:

```
ShallowWrapper.prototype.findByTestAttr = function (attr) {
  return this.find(`[data-test="${attr}"]`)
}
```